# GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6AC34U net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am abit new to nodejs and am working with socket.io. I keep getting this error on my browser console no matter what i try,even after viewing solutions given to another similar problem.
I am not sure if i setup everything correctly

Here is my code...

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session');
// const createPwa = require('create-pwa');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const morgan=require('morgan');
const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').strategy;

const FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session)

// io.on('connection',socket=>{
//     socket.emit('chat-message','Online')
// })
// io.emit('message', 'im testing');
module.exports={io:"io"}
const port = 8000;


...some code here...


// set the app to listen on the port
var server = http.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('server is running on port', server.address().port);
  });

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/assets')));
```

And in my template

```
...
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
```

Hope that is enough to help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Uncomment `io.on` and onwards, that is how the server listens for and initializes socket connections.

Comment: Can't beleieve it was as simple as that.Thanks, it worked!